# $1+\sqrt[3]{e^{2a}}\sqrt[5]{e^{b}}\sqrt[15]{e^{2c}} \leq \sqrt[3]{(1+e^{a})^2}\sqrt[5]{1+e^{b}}\sqrt[15]{(1+e^{c})^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, binomial-theorem

The inequality $1+\sqrt[3]{e^{2a}}\sqrt[5]{e^{b}}\sqrt[15]{e^{2c}} \leq \sqrt[3]{(1+e^{a})^2}\sqrt[5]{1+e^{b}}\sqrt[15]{(1+e^{c})^2}$ is true for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$?

I've tried to use the Bernoulli inequality $(1+k)^n \geq 1+kn$ but my inequality don't satisfy the conditions.

My other apporach was by the binomial theorem $(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}x^k$ but with non integer power I don't see a way here to solve it.

Comment: Do you known Holder inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking logs, this is 
$$\frac23\log(1+e^a)+\frac15\log(1+e^b)+\frac2{15}\log(1+e^c) \ge \log(1+e^{\frac23a+\frac15b+\frac2{15}c})$$
which follows from convexity of $\log(1+e^x)$ and Jensen's inequality.

Comment: Ah so that was the trick :)

Comment: @Steve The Holder solution is also quite straightforward and perhaps something you should learn.  In fact anything that can be done by Holder can also be done by AM-GM, though it will look quite complex.

Comment: @Steve: In fact, Jensen's inequality can be used to prove Holder's inequality in exactly the same way, and I would recommend learning how to use weighted Jensen's inequality as it is much more applicable than AM-GM outside contest mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use Holder inequality we have
$$(1+e^a)^{10}\cdot (1+e^b)^3\cdot(1+e^c)^{2}\ge (1+\sqrt[15]{e^{10a}\cdot e^{3b}\cdot e^{2c}})^{15}$$

I add $n=3$ Holder inequality proof,ie:
$$(a^3+b^3+c^3)(p^3+q^3+r^3)(u^3+v^3+w^3)\ge (apu+bqv+crw)^3,a,b,c,p,q,r,u,v,w>0$$
since
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\dfrac{a^3}{a^3+b^3+c^3}+\dfrac{p^3}{p^3+q^3+r^3}+\dfrac{u^3}{u^3+v^3+w^3}\right)=3$$
use AM-GM inequality we have
$$3\ge 3\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{apu}{\sqrt[3]{(a^3+b^3+c^3)(u^3+v^3+w^3)(p^3+q^3+r^3)}}$$
so
$$(a^3+b^3+c^3)(p^3+q^3+r^3)(u^3+v^3+w^3)\ge (apu+bqv+crw)^3$$
then you understand How to prove    general Holder inequality?

Comment: Thank you! I'll read about Holder inequality. But we don't have it on our course and this task was on one of the past exams. So there must exist a simply solution.

Comment: Holder inequality proof is very easy,only use AM-GM inequality

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder's_inequality This look super hard :( Let me think if I can understand these symbols.

Comment: @Steve: He is using a much simpler discrete variant of the inequality. Try finding elsewhere other than wikipedia.

Comment: Is the young's inequality sufficient?

Comment: @Steve,Now you have understand?

Comment: Not really, don't see yet connection between $(a^3+b^3+c^3)(p^3+q^3+r^3)(u^3+v^3+w^3)\ge (apu+bqv+crw)^3,a,b,c,p,q,r,u,v,w>0$ and my task. I kind of understand your proof

Comment: In Holder theorem we have $1/p + 1/q = 1$, what is $p$ in my case?

Comment: in fact we use genneral $\dfrac{1}{p}+\dfrac{1}{q}+\dfrac{1}{r}=1$,where your problem is $p=\dfrac{15}{10},q=5,r=\dfrac{15}{2}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25058/discussion-between-steve-and-math110).