# show this sequence always is rational number

Tags: recurrence-relations, contest-math

let $\{a_{n}\}$ such $a_{1}=-8$,and such
$$4\sqrt[3]{a_{n}}+5\sqrt[3]{a_{n+1}}=3\sqrt[3]{7(a_{n}+1)(a_{n+1}+1)}$$

show that
$$a_{n}\in Q,\forall n\in N^{+}$$

I  try let $a_{2}=x$,and for $n=1$, then we have
$$-8+5\sqrt[3]{x}=3\sqrt[3]{-49(x+1)}\Longrightarrow x=-1/8$$
and for $n=2$ I get $a_{3}=-\dfrac{389017}{4913}$ and so on

**The first observation**

i want use this well known identity: $$a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~if~~~~~ a+b+c=0$$
let $a=4\sqrt[3]{a_{n}},b=5\sqrt[3]{a_{n+1}},c=-3\sqrt[3]{7(a_{n}+1)(a_{n+1}+1)}$,so
$$64a_{n}+125a_{n+1}-189(a_{n}+1)(a_{n+1}+1)=-180\sqrt[3]{7a_{n}a_{n+1}(a_{n}+1)(a_{n+1}+1)}$$
**ADD it by 2021,11.6.PM.18:05**

**The second observation**

and Now I have found this interesting:
if $x,y,p,q,a,b\ge 0$, Hölder's inequality :
$$(x^3+y^3)(p^3+q^3)(a^3+b^3)\ge (xpa+yqb)^3$$
[$1+\sqrt[3]{e^{2a}}\sqrt[5]{e^{b}}\sqrt[15]{e^{2c}} \leq \sqrt[3]{(1+e^{a})^2}\sqrt[5]{1+e^{b}}\sqrt[15]{(1+e^{c})^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334701/1-sqrt3e2a-sqrt5eb-sqrt15e2c-leq-sqrt31ea2-s/1334718#1334718)
the condition it's
$$(a_{n}+1)(1+a_{n+1})(4^3+5^3)= (4\sqrt[3]{a_{n}}+5\sqrt[3]{a_{n+1}})^3$$
or
$$4\sqrt[3]{a_{n}}+5\sqrt[3]{a_{n+1}}=3\sqrt[3]{7(a_{n}+1)(a_{n+1}+1)}$$
but this sequence $a_{n}<0$ or $a_{n}>0$,so this Hölder inequality seem can't hold

Comment: where did you get this????

Comment: It comes from an online exam, which is now over, and there are no official answers

Comment: paste a link to the exam

Comment: soory,There are no websites, only groups

Comment: $a_3=(73/17)^3$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  yes, next $ \left( \frac{-65882}{90271} \right)^3 $  Actually, I got $a_3$  negative as well

Comment: so maybe $a_{n}=b^3_{n}$?,where $b_{n}\in Q$

Comment: Observe that $ a_n+1 =7c_n^3$, so we might want to study rational points on $7y^3 = x^3 + 1$.

Comment: As a starting point, define $b_1=-2$ and $b_{n+1}$ as the real solution to $-189 b_n^3 y^3-125 b_n^3+240 b_n^2 y+300 b_n y^2-64 y^3-189=0$. Then $a_n=b_n^3$

Comment: Using Mathematica I find 3 solutions for a[n+1] as 3 functions f, g, h, of a[n]. Starting with a[1]=-8 I find in each step one of the functions is rational, the two others have complex conjugate values. Picking each time the rational solution the first elements of the sequence (expressed here in decimal fractions approximation) are {-8., -0.125, -0.0126293, -0.388737, 11463.1, 29.4354, -0.927405, 4.14991, -0.996977, 1.02806, -1.00236, 0.256966} which looks rather erratic,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By looking at the initial values, we hypothesize that

- $a_n  = x_n^3, x_n \in \mathbb{Q}$
- $a_n + 1 = 7y_n^3, y_n \in \mathbb{Q}$

This suggests to study rational points on $7y^3 = x^3 + 1$.
We map $ a_i$ to the point $ ( \sqrt[3]{a_i}, \sqrt[3]{\frac{a_i + 1}{7} } )$.
We have the starting points $a_1: (-2, -1), a_2: (-1/2, 1/2)$.
Notice that we also have the rational points $ (-1, 0), (4/5, 3/5)$ on the curve. The latter was inspired by the coefficients in the question, and you will see how this is applicable in a moment.

We apply the usual tricks with group addition to determine the sequence.
Given a solution $(x,y)$, divide throughout by $x^3$ to get $ 7 (\frac{y}{x} ) ^3 = ( \frac{1}{x} ) ^3 + 1 $, so observe that $(\frac{1}{x}, \frac{y}{x} )$ is also a solution.
Given a solution $(x,y)$, we can construct the line that passes through $(x,y)$ and $(\frac{4}{5}, \frac{3}{5} )$ which intersects the cubic again at $(x', y')$.
Furthermore, if $(x,y)$ is a rational point, then so is $(x', y')$.  (Prove this.)

We combine this with the previous observation and send $(x,y)$ (to $(x',y')$ and then ) to $(\frac{1}{x'} , \frac{y'}{x'} ) $.

**Claim**: $(x,y)$ and $(\frac{1}{x'} , \frac{y'}{x'} )$ satisfy $4x + \frac{5}{x'} = 21 y \frac{y'}{x'}$.
See Zhaohui's solution for a beautiful proof that if the cubic intersects a line at 3 points, then $x_1x_2x_3 + 1  = 7 y_1y_2y_3$.
Applying it to the 3 points on the line, we get $\frac{4}{5} x x' + 1 = 7 \times \frac{3}{5} y y'$, and hence the claim follows.

**Corollary:** This shows that we send $ a_n : (x_n, y_n) $  to $a_{n+1} : (x_{n+1}, y_{n+1}) $ via the above description.
Since the starting point $a_1$ is rational, hence all of these are rational points.
So $ x_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $ a_n \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Notes

- Someone who is more familiar with elliptic curves might be able to manipulate the equations better. (IE See Zhaohui's solution)
- This approaches illustrates the theory behind the question, and why the question isn't just "magic".
- If one knew the fact that Zhaohui showed, then this approach would have felt natural. My guess is that similar questions like this can be dealt with in a similar way, especially for quadratic (and cubic) terms. Previously, I mainly dealt with similar questions previously via heavy-handed induction + guessing what the sequence is (EG Zhaohui's formulas at the end). I'm excited to apply this to future questions.
- For $a_1$, the line is actually tangential at $a_1$. So the 3rd point of intersection is $a_1$ (which explain why $a_1, a_2$ are related via $ (\frac{1}{x}, \frac{y}{x} )$.

---

**Uncompleted attempt at proof:** The line that passes through $(x,y)$ and $(\frac{4}{5}, \frac{3}{5} )$ is $ (Y' - y) ( \frac{4}{5} - x )  = (X' - x) ( \frac{3}{5} - y ) $, or that $Y' = X'\frac{5y-3}{5x-4} + \frac{3x-4y}{5x-4} $.
Substituting this into $7Y^3 = X^3 + 1$, and applying vieta's formula to find the sum of roots, we get that $\frac{4}{5} + x + x' = \frac{3 (\frac{5y-3}{5x-4})^2 (\frac{3x-4y}{5x-4}) } {1 - (\frac{5y-3}{5x-4})^3 } $, so $ x' = -\frac{625 x^4 - 1000 x^3 - 625 x y^3 + 675 x y + 370 x + 1000 y^3 - 900 y^2 - 148}{5 (5 x - 5 y - 1) (25 x^2 + 25 x y - 55 x + 25 y^2 - 50 y + 37))}$.
I'm unwilling to continue this tedious calculations, but one can find $y'$ and then verify that the equation holds.

Comment: wait, so can one prove the claim by just proceeding with the 'tedious calculation'? I don't think it should be too hard with Mathematica (for instance).

Comment: @mathworker21 I believe yes theoretically. Given that this is a contest-math problem, I didn't want to procceed with this approach.

Answer (score 10):

We could write a cubic curve in equation$\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3\sum_{k=1}^3a_{ijk}x_ix_jx_k=0$, where we use $x_1,x_2,x_3$ to replace symbol $x,y,1$ here. And the equation is symmetric so that $a_{123}=a_{321}$ etc, similar as a symmetric matrix could be used to represent a quadratic curve. And we could use symbol $A=(a_{ijk})$ to represent the 3-D tensor.

For any point in homogenous coordinates $p=(p_1,p_2,p_3), q=(q_1,q_2,q_3),r=(r_1,r_2,r_3)$, define $A_p=\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3\sum_{k=1}^3a_{ijk}p_ix_jx_k, A_{pq}=\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3\sum_{k=1}^3a_{ijk}p_iq_jx_k, A_{pqr}=\sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3\sum_{k=1}^3a_{ijk}p_iq_jr_k$.

If any point p in the cubic curve, we have $A_{ppp}=0$.

If a line intersect with the cubic curve in three different points p,q,r, we have $A_{pqr}=0$.

It is because for any p and q in the curve, we have $A_{ppp}=A_{qqq}=0$, using homogenous coordinates, for any point r in the line passing p&q, we have $r=p+\lambda q$, where $\lambda$ is a real number.

If r is also in the curve, we could have $A_{qqq}\lambda^3+3A_{qqp}\lambda^2+3A_{qpp}\lambda+A_{ppp}=0$.

Since $A_{qqq}=A_{ppp}=0$, we have $A_{qqp}\lambda+A_{qpp}=0$, or $ r=A_{qqp} p - A_{qpp} q$.

So $A_{pqr}=A_{qqp} A_{pqp} - A_{qpp}A_{pqq}$.

Since $A_{qqp}=A_{pqq}, A_{pqp}=A_{qpp}$, we got $A_{pqr}=0$.

Calvin has constructed cubic curve $x^3+1-7y^3=0$ so that it means that if a line intersect with the curve in $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2), (x_3,y_3)$, we must have $x_1x_2x_3+1-7y_1y_2y_3=0$.

Let $(x_3,y_3)=(\frac45,\frac35)$, we have $4x_1x_2+5=21y_1y_2$.

And according to Calvin's another construct, so that we could replace $(x_2,y_2)$ by  $(\frac{1}{x_4},\frac{y_4}{x_4})$ and get formula that $4x_1+5x_4=21y_1y_4$.

continue to use condition that 3 points in same line and finally we could get formula:

$\begin{cases}
u_1=-2,v_1=1,w_1=-1\\
u_{h+1}=-20u_h^2 + 16u_hv_h -63v_hw_h + 105w_h^2\\
v_{h+1}=25u_hv_h - 63u_hw_h-20v_h^2 + 84w_h^2\\
w_{h+1}=-12u_h^2 + 16u_hw_h -15v_h^2 + 25v_hw_h\\
a_h=(\frac{u_h}{v_h})^3
\end{cases}$

[image]
In the picture above, slope of $OA_h$ gives $\sqrt[3]{a_h}$, where $B_h, A_{h-1}, S$ is in one straight line and $A_h$ is the point of symmetry of $B_h$ about y=x. The orange curve is $x^3+y^3=7$. $S(\frac53, \frac43), A_1=B_2(-1,2)$

Weierstrass normal form $U^2=V^3-\frac2{6^37^4}$. $E_0: U_0=\frac1{9*6*7^2}, V_0=\frac{2}{3*6*7}, E_1: U_1=-\frac3{6*7^2}, V_1=\frac2{6*7}$
$x_h=\frac1{42V_h}+\frac{7U_h}{V_h}, y_h=\frac1{42V_h}-\frac{7U_h}{V_h}, a_h=\left(\frac{y_h}{x_h}\right)^3$. $E_h=(h-1)E_0+E_1$(Add in elliptic cure group)

pari/gp code

```
getslope(n)={
 local(E,S0,S1);
 local(R,V,U,x,y);
 E=ellinit([0,-2/(6^3*7^4)]);
 S0=[2/(3*6*7), 1/(9*6*7^2)];
 S1=[2/(6*7), -3/(6*7^2)];
 R=ellmul(E,S0,n-1);
 R=elladd(E,R,S1);
 V=R[1];
 U=R[2];
 x=1/(42*V)+7*U/V;
 y=1/(42*V)-7*U/V;
 y/x
}
```

```
? getslope(1)
%27 = -2
? getslope(2)
%28 = -1/2
? getslope(3)
%29 = -73/17
? getslope(4)
%30 = -65882/90271
? getslope(5)
%31 = 4309182809/191114642
```

Comment: Oh wow, that's a nice proof of the claim. I guessed that equation had to be true (esp given the coefficients), but didn't know how to prove it.  $\quad$ Note that your $A_{pq}, A_{pqr}$ definitions might have a typo since they are missing $q_j$.

Comment: updated, $p_j$ should be $q_j$

Comment: This is a really nice demonstration. Of course it needs to be hauled to completion which can be done with Calvin's observation, but I'm blown away by this!

Answer (score 7):

This problem is about the sequence $\,\{a_n\}\,$ where$\,a_ 1 = -8\,$
and it satisfies the recurrence relation
$$ 4\sqrt[3]{a_{n}}+5\sqrt[3]{a_{n+1}} = 
 3\sqrt[3]{7(a_{n}+1)(a_{n+1}+1)}. \tag{1} $$
Notice that the real cube root is a one-to-one and onto
function. Thus, define the related real sequence
$$ t_n := \sqrt[3]{a_{n}} \quad \text{ for all }\quad n>0. \tag{2} $$
Also, define the function
$$ f(u,v) := (4u + 5v)^3 - 3^3\,7(u^3+1)(v^3+1). \tag{3} $$
Notice that
$$ (u\,v)^3\, f(1/v,1/u) = f (u,v) \tag{4} $$
for all nonzero real $\,u,v.\,$ Now redefine $\,t_n\,$ as the
unique real solution to the recurrence relation
$$ f(t_{n-1}, t_n) = 0 \quad \text{ for all }\quad n>1. \tag{5} $$
Also, define $\,t_n\,$ for $n<1$ as the real solution to
$\,f(t_n,t_{n+1}) = 0\,$ and notice that
equation $(4)$ with equation $(5)$ together imply that
$$ t_n = 1/t_{3-n}\quad \text{ for all }\quad n\in \mathbb{Z}. \tag{6} $$

The question asks for a proof that $\,\{a_n\}\,$ is a rational sequence.
Since $\,a_n = t_n^3,\,$ It is sufficient to prove that $\,t_n=x_n/y_n\,$
for some rational sequences $\,x_n,y_n.\,$
The proof of this requires a lemma as follows.

**Lemma:** Define three sequences by recursion
$$ x_{n+1}  :=  12y_n^2 - 25x_nz_n,\;\;
y_{n+1} := 15x_n^2 - 16y_nz_n,\;\;
z_{n+1} := 20z_n^2 - 9x_ny_n. \tag{7} $$
using these sequences, define the special sequence
$$ e_n := x_n^3 + y_n^3 - 7z_n^3. \tag{8} $$
Verify using algebra that
$$ 4x_ny_{n+1} + 5y_nx_{n+1} - 21z_nz_{n+1} = 60e_n. \tag{9} $$
Also, verify that
$$ e_{n+1} \!=\! e_n (15x_n \!+\!12y_n \!+\!20z_n)
((15x_n)^2 \!+\!(12y_n)^2 \!+\!(20z_n)^2 
- 180(3x_ny_n \!+\!5x_nz_\!+\!4y_nz_n). \tag{10} $$
This implies that if $\,e_1 = 0\,$ then $e_n = 0\,$ for all $n>0.\,$
Using equation $(9)$ this implies that
$\, 4x_ny_{n+1} + 5y_nx_{n+1} - 21z_nz_{n+1} = 0\,$ for all $n>0.\,$
Also, verify that if $\,t_n:=x_n/y_n,\,$ then
$$ f(t_n,t_{n+1}) = e_n\frac{-27((5x_n - 4y_n)
  (25x_n^2 + 20x_ny_n + 16y_n^2))^2}{(y_ny_{n+1})^3}. \tag{11} $$
This implies that if $\,e_1=0\,$ then $\,f(t_n,t_{n+1}) = 0\,$
for all $n>0.\,$
Note that if the initial values $\,x_1,y_1,z_1\,$ are integers, then
$\,x_n,y_n,z_n\,$ are integers and hence $\,t_n\,$ are rational
for all $n>0.\,$
In the application of the lemma, let $\,x_1 = -2,\, y_1 = 1, \, z_1 = -1\,$ which
gives $\,e_1 = 0\,$ and hence
$$ x_n^3 + y_n^3 - 7z_n^3 = 0 \quad \text{ for all } n>0. \tag{12} $$
and also
$$ f(t_n,t_{n+1}) = 0  \quad \text{ for all } n>0. \tag{13} $$

As a check, here is a small table of sequence values:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
 n  &  x_n & y_n & z_n \\ \hline
 1 & -2 & 1 & -1 \\ \hline
 2 & -38 & 76 & 38 \\ \hline
 3 & 105412 & -24548 & 54872 \\ \hline
 4 & -137372929952 & 188227311856 & 83507611664 \\ \hline
 \end{array}$$
Note that $\,x:y:z = u:v:w\,$ from the Zhaohui Du answer.

Note that I used Mathematica to verify these computations.

### My original answer is below

This answer uses generalized Somos-$4$ sequences, which
are sequences that satisfy
$$ s_{n+2}s_{n-2} = p_1 s_{n+1}s_{n-1} + p_2 s_ns_n, \quad
\text{ for all }\quad n\in \mathbb{Z} $$
where $\,p_1,\,p_2\,$ are two parameters. In this question we have
$\,p_1 = -3721,\; p_2 = 1663260.\,$ Using these two parameters, define
the sequences $\,x_n,y_n,z_n\,$ with this recursion and initial values:
$$ x_0 = -17,\; x_1 = -2,\; x_2 = -1,\; x_3 = -73,\; z_2 = 1,\; z_3 = -38. $$
They satisfy the equations $\, z_n = z_{3-n}\,$ and $\, y_n = -x_{3-n} \,$
for all $\, n\in \mathbb{Z}.\,$
Now define $$ t_n := x_n/y_n,\qquad a_n := t_n^3. $$
The three sequences $\,x_n,y_n,z_n\,$ satisfy
$$ x_n^3 + y_n^3 = 7z_n^3,\quad 4x_ny_{n+1} + 5x_{n+1}y_n = 21z_nz_{n+1}. $$ These equations imply
$$ 4\sqrt[3]{a_{n}}+5\sqrt[3]{a_{n+1}}=3\sqrt[3]{7(a_{n}+1)(a_{n+1}+1)}.$$
Note that all sequences here except $\,t_n\,$ and $\,a_n\,$ are
integer sequences, although it is sufficient that $\,x_n,y_n,z_n\,$
are rational sequences which implies that $\,t_n\,$ and hence $\,a_n\,$
are rational sequences also.

As a check, here is a small table of sequence values:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline
 n  &  x_n & y_n & z_n \\ \hline
 1  & -2 & 1 & -1 \\ \hline
 2  & -1 & 2 & 1 \\ \hline
 3  & -73 & 17 & -38 \\ \hline
 4  & -65882 & 90271 & 40049 \\ \hline
 5  & -4309182809 & -191114642 & -2252725111 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Note that $\,x:y:z = u:v:w\,$ from the Zhaohui Du answer.

L. E. Dickson, *History of the Theory of Numbers*, Volume II, Chapter XXI, section "Numbers the sum of two rational cubes: $x^3+y^3=Az^3$, pp. $572$-$578$ has several solutions for $\,A=7.$

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but can you explain how you got $3721$ and $1663260$? Keep in mind that this is a contest question : if you've derived this information from some kind of computer program, then you should be stating it.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thank you for your helpful comment! I appreciate it. Yes, I used Mathematica and PARI/gp. I will try to include relevant details later. I do not see any evidence that this is a "contest question". The bounty just asks "for **an answer from a reputable source**".

Comment: Ah yes, you're right : there's no evidence of this being a contest question, I probably got carried away because the other attempts were made in this spirit. Having said that , I will wait for your details, thanks and +1.

Comment: (I'm impressed that you're posting an answer using something named after you!) I don't have any experience with Somos sequence other than a quick Wikipedia read, so I apologize if this is a basic/obvious question. Is the relationship between those sequences and elliptic curves well understood? EG Can we relate an integer somos sequence to rational points on a curve?

Comment: @CalvinLin  Thanks for your comment! There **is** a relation between rational points on elliptic curves, but "well understood" is not quite there yet. For a positive example, see [OEIS sequence A006769](https://oeis.org/A006769). For this question I have an [elliptic curve $E: y^2 + y = x^3 - 331$](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/441/d/1) and point $(21,94)$ but I have not got all the details I would like yet. The curve has $j$-invariant $0$.

Comment: The lemma seems magical to me. How did it arise? EG Was it from some underlying theory?

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks for your comment! There are several underlying theories, but I am not an expert in any of them. I only have lots of experience with sequences defined by linear and nonlinear recursions such as Somos sequences. I may later add a bit more explanation of the different sequence recursions that appear in my answer.

Comment: @CalvinLin and I am still working on the connection with elliptic curves and other cases of $x^3+y^3=Az^3$ but it is taking much more time than I expected. Same thing with nonlinear recursions.I will try to have an updated solution with more details by years end.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't an answer, really more of a musing on the problem, a full expression for $a_{n+1}$ in terms of $a_n$, and a way forward. Assuming that this problem is well posed (that is, $a_n$ can always be calculated from $a_{n-1}$ without ambiguity) then to get this expression, define $a_n=b_n^3$. Then the formula relating the $n$th and $(n+1)$th members (after cubing both sides) becomes

$$0=(4 b_n + 5 b_{n+1})^3 - 27 (7 (b_n^3 + 1) (b_{n_+1}^3 + 1))$$

$$=-189 b_{n+1}^3 b_n^3-125 b_n^3+240 b_{n+1} b_n^2+300 b_{n+1}^2 b_n-64 b_{n+1}^3-189$$

Since we are assuming that this cubic in $b_{n+1}$ has one real solution (otherwise the problem would be ill-posed) we can solve for $b_{n+1}$ in terms of $b_n$:

$$b_{n+1}=3 \sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{2}} \left(\sqrt[3]{-\frac{125 b_n^6+61 b_n^3-64}{\left(189
   b_n^3+64\right){}^2}-\frac{23625 b_n^9+27721 b_n^6+8192 b_n^3+4096}{\left(189
   b_n^3+64\right){}^3}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{125 b_n^6+61 b_n^3-64}{\left(189
   b_n^3+64\right){}^2}-\frac{23625 b_n^9+27721 b_n^6+8192 b_n^3+4096}{\left(189
   b_n^3+64\right){}^3}}\right)-\frac{100 b_n}{-189 b_n^3-64}$$

We then use the above expression to get an expression for $a_{n+1}$ which is

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{\left(100 \sqrt[3]{a_n}-45\  \sqrt[3]{49a_n^2 \left(a_n+1\right)}-48
    \sqrt[3]{7\left(a_n+1\right){}^2}\right){}^3}{\left(189
   a_n+64\right){}^3}$$

One method to go forward here is to assume that $a_n=r^3$, and then it is sufficient to show that

$$a_n+1=7q^3$$

(for some rational $q$). This is because if this is the case then $a_{n+1}$ can also be written as $s^3$ for some rational $s$. Of course, it is not enough to simply assume $a_n=r^3$ because there are many rational $r$ for which the above equation does not hold (for example $r=1$). It is only for some $r$ (for example $r=-2$) where the above expression evaluates correctly and showing that this will always be the case for $a_n$ seems to be the difficult thing.