# Decompose an integer into the cubic sum of two rational numbers

Tags: number-theory

For the equation

$$n = x^3 + y^3 + z^3, n\in\mathbb{Z}, (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{Q}.$$

*Ryley's Theorem* states that:

$$
n=
\left(n+\frac{1}{3}\right)^3 + 
\left(\frac{3 n-9 n^2}{9 n^2-3 n+1}\right)^3+
\left(\frac{9 n-27 n^3-1}{27 n^2-9 n+3}\right)^3 .
$$

So any integer can be decomposed into the sum of cubes of three rational numbers.

---

I would like to know for

$$n = x^3 + y^3, n\in\mathbb{Z}, (x,y)\in\mathbb{Q},$$

Does a similar rational decomposition exist?

Comment: This is a very subtle question, but not all integers can be written in this way.  For example, if $n = p$ is a prime congruent to $2$ or $5 \pmod 9$ (or $n = 3$), then it can't be expressed as a sum of two rational cubes.  See e.g. [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~rosu/main.pdf), page 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\,n=x^3+y^3\,$ with rational $\,x,y.\,$ Use a common denominator
to get $\,n=(X/Z)^3+(Y/Z)^3\,$ where $\,X,Y,Z\,$ are integers.
Simplify to get
$$ X^3+Y^3=nZ^3. \tag{1} $$
It is well known that if $\,n=1\,$ then by Fermat's Last
Theorem there is no nontrivial solution in integers and
thus there is no solution such as you propose.

The general case is treated in
L. E. Dickson, *History of the Theory of Numbers*, Volume II, Chapter XXI, section "Numbers the sum of two rational cubes: $x^3+y^3=Az^3$, pp. $572$-$578$.

The [OEIS sequenceA020897](https://oeis.org/A020897) lists integers
which are the sum of two nonzero rational cubes. The answers
to [MSE question 4298049](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4298049) are about the case $\,n=7\,$ which depends on
the rational points of an elliptic curve. Even though rational
solutions exist, there is no parametrized rational solutions
such as you propose.