# Infinitely many solution of $x^3 + y^3 + 7z^3 = 0$ on $\mathbb{Z}^3$ with gcd $=1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

I am reading a textbook on undergraduate-level abstract algebra to have a break. I want to prove that the equation
\[
x^3 + y^3 + 7z^3 = 0 \tag{1}
\]
has infinitely many solution on $\mathbb{Z}^3$ with $\gcd(x, y, z) = 1$.

I want to use the following map. If $(x, y, z)$ is a solution of (1) and we define
\[
x’ = x(y^3 - 7z^3), \ \ \ \ y’ = y(7z^3 - x^3), \ \ \ \ z’ = z(x^3 - y ^3), \tag{2}
\]
then, $(x’, y’, z’)$ is also a solution of (1). I also know that $(-2, 1, 1)$ is a solution of (1), but, to gain the “next” solution of this by (2), we have $(12, 15, -9)$, whose gcd is not $1$.

I don’t see whether this is helpful or not, but, according to SageMath, we have
\[
x’^3 + y’^3 + 7z’^3 = (- x + y)(x^2 + xy + y^2)(x^3 - 7z^3)(y^3 - 7z^3)(x^3 + y^3 + 7z^3).
\]

What I am thinking are difficult can be divided into the following two questions. First, how can we overcome the obstacle of the constraint that gcd should be $1$? Second, how can we check that solutions obtained by using (1) are all different with gcd $= 1$?

P.S. There will be many approaches to solve this problem, but I wonder if there is a solution where we use the map (2), if possible, thanks.

Comment: Compare with my answer to [MSE question 4298049](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4298049/) especially the reference to Dickson's History and my generalized Somos-4 sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Comment: Your way of prove is not suitable because:

If $a+b+c=0$ then:

$a^3+b^3+c^3=\lambda(a)(b)(c)$

$(y^3-7z^3)^3+(7z^3-x^3)^3+(x^3-y^3)^3=\lambda(y^3-7z^3)(7z^3-x^3)(x^3-y^3)=0$

Which results in:

$gcd(x, y, z)\neq 1$

But you can rewrite equation like:

$x^3+y^3+(2z)^3=z^3$

You can see a better way to show this equation has infinite solutions in my answer to this question:

math.stackexchange.com/questions/4420427/

Answer (score 0):

I like your method of obtaining a "next" solution. Here's one thought on how to improve it - if $(x, y, z)$ is a solution to the equation, then $\left(\frac{x}{\gcd(x, y, z)}, \frac{y}{\gcd(x, y, z)}, \frac{z}{\gcd(x, y, z)} \right)$ is also a solution to the equation where $\gcd\left(\frac{x}{\gcd(x, y, z)}, \frac{y}{\gcd(x, y, z)}, \frac{z}{\gcd(x, y, z)} \right) = 1$.

In the example you gave, $(12, 15, -9)$ does not have gcd equal to 1, but $(4, 5, -3) = \left(\frac{12}{\gcd(12, 15, -9)}, \frac{15}{\gcd(12, 15, -9)}, \frac{-9}{\gcd(12, 15, -9)} \right)$ does have gcd equal to 1.